# monic polynomial integer coefficients all of roots is $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}$ and such $|a_{i}|<1(i=1,2,\cdots,n-1)$

Tags: polynomials

Give a monic polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients all of roots is $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}$ and such
$$|a_{i}|<1(i=1,2,\cdots,n-1)$$
and $a_{i}\neq 0(i=1,2,\cdots,n)$, if $a^2_{i}=a_{j}\cdot a_{k}$,show that $i=j=k$

Has anyone seen this  before, or can you give a counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest examples of polynomials as above are $x^2-x-1, x^3-x-1, x^4-x^3-1$. It is not that difficult to show that there are polynomials like that for any degree using a little geometric theory of numbers. Note that all such polynomials must be irreducible over the integers since there is no monic integral polynomial with all non-zero roots and all strictly less than $1$ in absolute value.

Minimal polynomials for [Pisot numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PisotNumber.html) are precisely of this type (Pisot numbers are positive real algebraic integers for which all their conjugates are less than $1$ in absolute value)

Since there is a $\mathbb Q(a_1,a_2,..a_n)$ automorphism $\sigma$ that takes $a_i$ to $a_1$ (the unique root of modulus greater than $1$), we get $a_1^2=\sigma(a_j)\sigma(a_k)$ which implies $\sigma(a_j)=\sigma(a_k)=a_1$ so $a_i=a_j=a_k$